# Selecting a Bayes shrinkage prior

Tags: prior, hierarchical-bayesian, regularization

I'm looking for a way to integrate prior knowledge about a parameter in a context equivalent to Bayesian hierarchical models. I come from frequentist background and I'm uninitiated in hierarchical models, but I've got a gut feeling that this could solve my problem.
Given an $L_1$ shrunken OLS regression problem I assume that the regression coefficients are normally distributed
$$
\beta_1 \sim {\mathcal N}(\mu,1),
$$
and its mean follows a double exponential (Laplacian) distribution 
$$
\mu \sim {\rm}(\frac{1}{2c} exp{(-\frac{|\mu|}{c}}))
$$

Now, suppose I know from previous studies that a certain effect size has been reported. How can I integrate that knowledge into choosing the correct parameter $c$ for the Laplacian distribution? Any thoughts or ideas? I'm using this in the context of LASSO regression so I don't see how I could easily specify a hyperprior for $c$